# Kerberos and Nodejs on mac

Tags: node.js, kerberos

I have to install a project which has krb5(npm package) as a dependency but when "npm install", I'm getting this error,

```
./src/krb5_bind.cc:635:13: error: no matching function for call to 'krb5_get_init_creds_password'
      err = krb5_get_init_creds_password(krb_context, 
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:2302:1: note: candidate function not viable: 4th
      argument ('const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *'
      (aka 'const char *')) would lose const qualifier
krb5_get_init_creds_password
^
../src/krb5_bind.cc:699:13: warning: 'krb5_init_context' is deprecated: use GSS.framework [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      err = krb5_init_context(&context);
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1434:19: note: 'krb5_init_context' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
        (krb5_context *) KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED("use GSS.framework") __API_DEPRECATED("Use GSS.framework", macos(10.0...
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:73:53: note: expanded from macro
      'KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED'
#define KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED(x) __attribute__((deprecated(x)))
                                                    ^
../src/krb5_bind.cc:750:13: warning: 'krb5_kt_resolve' is deprecated: use GSS.framework [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      err = krb5_kt_resolve(krb_context, kt_name.c_str(), &ktid);
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1682:19: note: 'krb5_kt_resolve' has been explicitly
      marked deprecated here
                krb5_keytab * ) KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED("use GSS.framework") __API_DEPRECATED("Use GSS.framework", maco...
                                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:73:53: note: expanded from macro
      'KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED'
#define KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED(x) __attribute__((deprecated(x)))
                                                    ^
../src/krb5_bind.cc:815:13: error: no matching function for call to 'krb5_get_init_creds_keytab'
      err = krb5_get_init_creds_keytab(krb_context,
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:2314:1: note: candidate function not viable: 6th
      argument ('const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *'
      (aka 'const char *')) would lose const qualifier
krb5_get_init_creds_keytab
^
17 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

I am running on mac os and I doubt that it is using the Kerberos from the Mac OS rather than taking it from the krb5 dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile MIT Kerberos manual,

```
wget https://kerberos.org/dist/krb5/1.19/krb5-1.19.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf krb5-1.19.1.tar.gz
cd krb5-1.19.1.tar.gz/src
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

See: https://github.com/adaltas/node-krb5/issues/10#issuecomment-426997642